# How do I know what packages are named with apt-get?

Tags: linux, terminal, apt-get, linux-mint

Linux noob here.
I want to download a program. Lets say this time its an ssh server.

How do I know what to type in `sudo apt-get ???? install`?

I tried `ssh` and `sshserver` just off the top of my head, but they didn't work.

Is there a search function or something?

Comment: Seems like this would be a better fit for serverfault.com :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`apt-cache search` is what you might find useful.  `apt-cache search ssh server` should show you the relevant packages.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash-completion` package installed, you can try doing :

`sudo apt-get install openss`<kbd>tab</kbd>

you will find :

> openssh-blacklist        openssh-blacklist-extra  openssh-client           openssh
>   server           openssl                  openssl-blacklist        openssl-blacklist-extra